# How do I override broken Windows Consistent User Interface standard (CUI) cut behaviour in Discord?

Tags: linux, windows-10, discord

An unfixed bug in a recent version of Discord means that `Shift`+`Del` now *deletes* rather than *cuts* text, and I've been getting increasingly annoyed at losing text because of my natural instinct to use `Shift`+`Del` to *cut* text rather than `Ctrl`+`X`.

I forget that it's not working, *cut* the text in the way I've always done, and go to *paste* it elsewhere, only to find that while the text is gone in it's original location, and it isn't in the paste buffer. If I haven't done anything else, I can often `Ctrl`+`Z` to get the text back, but if I've done too much, that doesn't work.

`Shift`+`Del` works fine with other applications, so is there any way to disable this unwanted keyboard shortcut override in Discord at the OS level, and restore the expected behaviour where `Shift`+`Del` is synonymous with `Ctrl`+`X`?

<sup>Discord Stable 101451 (b46c230) Host 1.0.9003 Windows 10 64-Bit (10.0.19041)</sup>

According to [Eldritch Conundrum](https://superuser.com/users/120178/eldritch-conundrum) in comments, this problem is also seen with Discord on Linux.

Comment: Since 1987 the key has been Ctrl+X and not Shift+Del from Word for Dos. See IBM's CUA Guidelines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access which is the basis of Windows User Interface Guidelines.. Programs implement guidelines. Programs decide what key cuts.

Comment: TIL that Shift-Del cuts. Just tried it in Notepad, it works indeed.

Comment: I don't see how your comment helps me improve my question @user1292580. Also, I don't see what Word has to do with this, and Windows CUI is based on IBM CUA and the IBM CUA page you linked to specifies Shift+Del, not Ctrl+X. Both Cut methods have co-existed since before most people started using computers, so for one to work when the other doesn't is very jarring.

Comment: Anyone want to suggest why my question might have been down voted? I can't see how it is unclear or not useful. No judgement, I just want to understand how I can write more acceptable questions here in the future.

Comment: *disable this erroneous keyboard shortcut override in Discord at the OS level*. **No**. Programs decide what keys they support through an Accelerator table table. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/keyboard-accelerators. You can always edit Discords with ResHacker but some programs build the table in memory rather than as an embedded text file - http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/.

Comment: Ok, I've changed *erroneous* to *unwanted* @user1292580, even though it's almost certainly an error rather than an intentional change. The standard `Ctrl`+`Del` cut functionality worked fine in previous versions of Discord and it's not like Discord now uses this key combination for anything else, it's just stopped it having it's standard function.

Comment: Oh, and few applications are written directly in Win32 these days, most applications are build using frameworks pre-populate the accelerator table with all of the standard defaults, like both `Ctrl`+`x` and `Shift`+`Del for Cut. These only stop working if an application then specifically overrides them, either intentionally, or accidentally.

Comment: I have the same problem but on Discord for Linux. The rare applications that don't support shift+del are a major pain with my decades of muscle memory.

Comment: Thanks @EldritchConundrum, I've updated the question and [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1684697/16858) to mention this. I don't run Discord on Linux myself, so I can't test it, but feel free to let me know, or add an answer, if you do get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Discord on Windows

After reading [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1684688/16858), and reading the documentation, I found that the following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script was able to fix the `Shift`+`Del` behaviour in Discord:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Discord.exe
+Del::
Send, {Ctrl down}x{Ctrl up}
```

It seems that when the documentation says *this method is more secure* it can also mean *this can work in situations where the other method doesn't*.

I don't know why [harrymc's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1684688/16858) didn't work for Discord, but my suspicion is that something about Discords input handling means that `+Del::^x` resulted in the broken `Shift`+`Del` behaviour being suppressed rather than it being fix, it just seems to ignore AutoHotkeys `^x` instruction, and it's probably the same reason for the `Shift`+`Del` behaviour breaking in the first place.

#### Discord on Linux

Although originally about Discord on Windows, [Eldritch Conundrum](https://superuser.com/users/120178/eldritch-conundrum) said they had the same problem on Linux. According to suggestions in [AutoHotkey equivalent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165124/6403) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) it's possible that [IronAHK](https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK), [sikuli](http://sikulix.com/), [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), [xautomation](https://linux.die.net/man/7/xautomation) or [AutoHotkey under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5173) might help solve this problem on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To replace
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
by
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,
but only in Discord, you could use this AutoHotkey script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Discord.exe
+Del::^x
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: That looked promising, and it did suppress the deletion, but it didn't actually perform a cut, and the past buffer remained unchanged. *8'(

Comment: I don't have Discord, but is Ctrl+X not the right combination for doing Cut?

Comment: `Ctrl+X` is the shortcut for a cut operation within WIndows no matter which application you are in provided the application supports Clipboard integration.

Comment: @Ramhound: Not universally true. See for example CMD.

Comment: @harrymc - How about this then, Ctrl+X is supported by Discord, in my testing, it cuts the selected text and does not "delete it".  `Shift+Delete` isn't a shortcut even familiar with, it seems like it would just delete, the selected text.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`x` does work in Discord @harrymc, as I implied in my question, but as I said in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1684697/16858), doing `^x` in AutoHotkey doesn't work, whereas `Send, {Ctrl down}x{Ctrl up}` does work. I have no idea why, but I'd guess that Discord is doing something strange with it's input handling, and that's also what's causing the bug which prevents `Shift`+`Del` from working too.

Comment: The `Shift`+`Del` method of cutting originated with IBM, while the `Ctrl`+`x` method of cutting originated with Xerox PARC, was adopted by Apple and adapted by Microsoft, in addition to the IBM method @Ramhound. Both have their place, but `Shift`+`Del` and `Shift`+`Ins` are particularly useful when moving blocks of text, since `Shift`+`Home`, `Shift`+`End`, `Shift`+<direction> and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+<direction> are all very close together. It depends on what you're used to but after years of using both I find it far more natural than being forced to use only `Ctrl`+`x`.